# python remove elements from one list based on indices from another list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have 2 lists. First list is a list of values, `values`, second list is a list of indices, `position`.

```
position = [1, 0 ,0 ]
values = [2, 6, 1]

output: [] # empty list since all elements are removed
```

what i want to do is, iterate the `position` list and remove the corresponding element at that position in the `values` list.

- So, in first pass, it will remove `values[position[0]]`, that is `6`, then the resultant `values` array will also change to `[2, 1]`.
- In the second pass, it will remove `values[position[1]]`, that is `2`, and the resultant `values` array will become `[1]`.
- Lastly it will remove `1`.

This is my code in O(n**2).
Any optimization is appreciated. Thanks!

```
position = [1, 0 ,0 ]
values = [2, 6, 1]
for i in range(len(position)):
    while len(values) > 0:
        x = values[position[i]]
        print(x)
        values.remove(x)
        break
```

Comment: That is not really remove, but rearrange

Comment: arrays are not meant for efficient arbitrary deletion. Unless you change your data structure, every deletion will be linear. You can use a tree map type data structure, like sorted containers in python, that will sacrifice some access time for better deletion/insertion time. Then your algorithm works in linearithmic time.

Comment: Your explanation of the algorithm is very vague. Could you not just remove each `ith` index for `i` in `position`?

Comment: it is not n**2 : your while loop isn't really one; as you have a break, you can just remove the while

Comment: Shouldn't the output be an empty list?

Comment: @burningalc yes the list will be empty, i need to print the elements in order they get removed

Comment: @azro, got it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you can use the `.pop()` method.

```sh
position = [1, 0 ,0 ]
values = [2, 6, 1]

for idx in position:
    values.pop(idx)
```

Answer (score 2):

First note: your while loop is useless, as you break at first iteration. Your loop is strictly equivalent to

```
for i in range(len(position)):
    x = values[position[i]]
    print(x)
    values.remove(x)
```

---

Then : iterate over values and not indices for `position`, and use `list.pop` to get and remove at the same time

```
result = []
for pos in position:
    result.append(values.pop(pos))
print(result)  # [6, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner using a list comprehension: `result = [values.pop(pos) for pos in position]`

Comment: yes my bad, while loop is not adding any value